# Javascript - Calculating monetary totals

Tags: javascript

I have a page on a site that calculates rate totals for a rental, which are optional. The javascript serves nothing more but to show you the updated total if you select or unselect checkbox options.

Here is what I've tried. It appears to work, but it is adding 2 cents to every other click for one of the checkboxes, I believe because toFixed rounds. How can I keep the number from rounding?

```
function update_rate(state, amount, field) {
        if (state == true) {
            rate = parseFloat($('span.rateTotal').text()) + amount;
            rate = rate.toFixed(2);
            due = parseFloat($('span.'+field).text()) + amount;
            due = due.toFixed(2);
            $('span.rateTotal').text(rate);
            $('span.'+field).text(due);
        } else {
            rate = parseFloat($('span.rateTotal').text()) - amount;
            rate = rate.toFixed(2);
            due = parseFloat($('span.'+field).text()) - amount;
            due = due.toFixed(2);
            $('span.rateTotal').text(rate);
            $('span.'+field).text(due);
        }
    }
```

Checkbox HTML:

```
<cfinput type="checkbox" name="linen_service" id="linen_service" checked="checked" value="0" onClick="update_rate(this.checked, #reservationQuery[7].xmlChildren[i]['dblAmount'].xmlText#, 'second-due');" />
```

Basically passes in the amount of the option, checkbox state, and the name of the field that should be affected.

Edit: Fiddle URL: http://jsfiddle.net/nGrVf/6/

Comment: toFixed is not a javascript native function.  Can you please post the code you have for that method.

Comment: have you tried toFixed first and then parseFloat? @Evan toFixed is a javascript native function https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: If you could set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) scenario it would aid us in helping.

Comment: @Evan Larsen *toFixed is not al javascript native function*? `(12).toFixed` outputs: `function toFixed() { [native code] }`

Answer (score 1):

Are you stuck with your your types?

I find it is almost always better to store monetary values in whole numbers of the lowest unit (e.g, cents, or pence) and then add the decimal point two places from the right when displaying.

So the conversions might look like:

```
var dollars = 100.43;
var cents = Math.round(dollars * 100);

//convert for display
var sCents = String(cents);
var display = sCents.substr(0, sCents.length-2) + "." + sCents.substr(sCents.length-2,2);
alert(display);
```

Can be seen here at http://jsfiddle.net/jameswiseman76/jhjtP/

Then you don't have to worry about any ugly floating point conversions.

Comment: Where does the 'a' come in above? Its undefined.

Comment: Sorry, that was a hangover from a previous version. I renamed to values to be more meaningful (and resisted the temptation to use "pounds" and "pence" :-)) - Now resolved

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this adds two '.' into my end result. Any ideas?

Comment: @Kevin: Are you sure you are mulitplying your values out? can you feed your values into this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/58QEH/

Comment: @JamesWiseman I can acheive the same problem Kevin states.  Remember, he is having float problems so his number isn't `100.43`, it's probably `100.43049583498534` - and your code gives an odd output with multiple decimals in this case...

Comment: Good point! Have corrected to do a `Math.round` on the number. My point still stands, though. Unless you want to retain fractions of a cent, then its better to represent your number as an integer, not a a floating point.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can think up is to round it down (using muls and `floor`): i.e.

```
rate = Math.floor(rate * 100)/100;
```

**Edit:** After a bit of testing, I found that there is nothing wrong with the given code. This means the calculation error comes from another part of the code or from the unknown `amount` variable.

Comment: Seems to occur when the amount contains a decimal. If I pass in 190, its fine. But if I pass 104.93, thats when it starts adding in 2 cents per click.

Comment: Please give a live example orenough for us to recreate the problem. I can't seem to reproduce it: http://jsfiddle.net/nGrVf/.

Comment: Here is one using real numbers: http://jsfiddle.net/nGrVf/6/ . It seems to work on Fiddle, but not in my dev environment.

Comment: I must reiterate that the code you're giving is fine. Use a javascript  debugger, and track the variables to see where the error is. (I'm using DevTools, but Firebug works too)

Comment: Also using jQuery 1.2.3 if that matters.